# Completely stop an android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android webview and allow the user to use their own javascript inside a window.onload callback (its completely isolated and I personally don't see a security risk). The problem occurs if something like the following is entered

```
while(true){
}
```

In the java side of things, I start a timer and after about 5 seconds if JavaScript is still going I try to stop the webview. I have tried various things:

```
webView.stopLoading();
webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
webView.freeMemory();
webView.pauseTimers();
webView.destroy();
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView").getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null).invoke(webView, (Object[]) null);
```

each one getting a little more desperate :). Nothing works and a thread continues to use up the processor until I quit the app. Does anyone know how I can stop it correctly?

Any help is much appreciated,
Ian

Comment: I'm not really answering my own question so I won't post an answer but the solution I went with in the end was to use a standalone javascript engine. These are often more flexible than hacking it with a webview.

Comment: why not answering your own question? Been looking all day here on SO and have found some posts about this however none provide any kind of answer.

Comment: Apologies, I mean to say my solution doesn't answer the original question so I posted it as a comment.

Comment: use JavaScript Lint to check for that kind of errors before executing the JavaScript generated by a user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling JavaScript before destroying the WebView?  It seems like the JavaScript interpreter is outliving your WebView, but perhaps if you tell it to stop executing, then you will solve your problem.  I'd try using this at the top of your timed method:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```