# Cannot load a Webview inside a dialogfragment if previouse load didnt complete the javascript

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview inside a dialog fragment. When I press a button the webview is loaded with an URL, than a javascript is run (the javascript takes about 2min, depending on the URL inside the webview).

So far so good. However, if I backpress the dialogfragment while the javascript is running and than open the dialogfragment again I cannot load a webview anymore. Infact, non of my webviews can be loaded after if I do the above, even webviews on different fragments, they are all just blank.

But if I let the script finish, everything is OK, and I can load another URL or open another webview inside another fragment.

So I think that the webview doesn't get completely destroyed when I backpress and abort a javascript load inside my dialog fragment.

I know from Log.i that the dialogfragment onDestroy gets called on backpress. This is how that method looks like.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("DialogFragment", "onDestory");
    preViewHtml.destroy();
}
```

But I have also tried to close/remove everything I can think of like.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("CONVERTERDIlog", "onDestory");
    preViewHtml.removeJavascriptInterface("MyJavaScript");
    preViewHtml.clearHistory();
    preViewHtml.clearCache(true);
    preViewHtml.loadUrl("about:blank");
    preViewHtml.pauseTimers();
    preViewHtml.destroy();
}
```

Any Idea how to solve this?

**EDIT**
Its actually seems to load eventually, but there is a huge delay the second time. First time the webview loads after 2sec (and script finishes in 2min), second time if I abort the view before the script has finished the delay is about 1 min to load the webview (script time after the view has loaded is unaffected).

Its like the script continues to load on the webview even If I close that fragment (backpress), and I have to wait for the script from before to finish before I can load another webview. But I want the script to stop when the webview is destroyed of course.

This is my scrip method which the program seems to be stuck with and needs to be completed (cannot be aborted for some reason).

```
private void colorizeHtmlWithJavaScript() {
    preViewHtml.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');" +

                    //A long for loop using alpha on an HTML, //I think it is this loops which continues to run somehow. +

                    "})()");


        }
    });
```

And how I set up the webview.

```
private void setUpWebView() {
    preViewHtml = (WebView) theView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    preViewHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    preViewHtml.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(theView.getContext()), "HtmlViewer");


}
```

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457548/completely-stop-an-android-webview) seems to have had the same issue as me, but no answers to that thread.
And on [google Dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) I can see that they write "your JavaScript runs in another thread and not" which means that I have to find a way to kill/stop that thread! I cannot read the whole page yet, since I am still in China for some time and google Is blocked here.

Answer (score 0):

use `preViewHtml.stopLoading();`,So rewrite your destroy() method as

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("DialogFragment", "onDestory");
    preViewHtml.loadUrl("about:blank"); 
    preViewHtml.stopLoading();
    preViewHtml.setWebChromeClient(null);
    preViewHtml.setWebViewClient(null);
    preViewHtml.destroy();
    preViewHtml= null;
}
```

also pause and resume webview as

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    preViewHtml.onPause();
    preViewHtml.pauseTimers(); 
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    preViewHtml.onResume();
    preViewHtml.resumeTimers();
}
```

Reference : [WebView stopLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#stopLoading())

Comment: @user3711421 is preViewHtml your webview?

Comment: @user3711421 see edited answer and don't forget clear project before retry.