# Manually kill the javascript thread

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

Is it possible to kill threads in android I see there is a

```
Thread.currentThread().destroy();
```

which however is deprecated and still doesn't work for me. Im in china at the moment without working VPN so cannot read android dev, but I know it says there that javascript inserted in a webview will run in a separate thread.

The problem is that this thread is not killed even though the webview and fragment is destroyed. So it continues the script even though I want it to be aborted/stoped/destroyed (whatever).

Comment: the thread? How do I make a thread null? this doesn't work Thread.currentThread() = null; //

Comment: you can use runnable and handler instead.. use a boolean to stop the runnable like this `void Run(){  if (!continue) { mhandler.post(this)} }`

Comment: actually this is what I am looking at not, day 2 of my search for a solution. Looking for ways to implement is.. But wouldn't the script be run in a separate unrelated thread anyhow? I mean as soon as I run it from my handler?  How do you mean I should implement this?

Comment: `Thread.interrupt()` use this if you dont want the runnable and handler instead.. [Stopping a thread](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/stopping_thread.shtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `mWebView.destroy();` when you want to stop javascript. It works for me to stop playing music after Activity destroyed. I call that method in the `onDestroy()` of my Activity.

Here is the document of that method:

> public void destroy ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Destroys the internal state of this WebView. This
>   method should be called after this WebView has been removed from the
>   view system. No other methods may be called on this WebView after
>   destroy.

**Update:**

I find another working solution. Its key idea is to load another url if you want to stop the javascript in the previous url. So you can put a blank html file in your asset and load it when you want to stop your time consuming javascript. Code like this:

```
appWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/infAppPaused.html");
```

Please refer to the post [here](http://www.mcseven.me/2011/12/how-to-kill-an-android-webview/#The-Problem-1).

**Update 1:**
A finally working solution for the problem in this post.

Add a check state method in the JavaScriptInterface class and call that method during the processing loop and quit the loop if state is not match. Then the javascript will stop if you change the state to "quit state" when your fragment destroyed.

Here is code example:

```
private boolean webviewAlive = true;
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public boolean checkState() {
        return webviewAlive;
    }

}

// Init WebView 
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(),
        "HtmlViewer");

// To stop the javascript loop
webviewAlive = false;

// Call check state method in javascript loop
if(!window.HtmlViewer.checkState()){
    // break the javascript
}
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried this and it seems to kill the webview but somehow the javascript thread seems to live on. Worth to mention is that the webview is housed by a fragment and not activity..... But you are sure that your script is aborted when you close the activity? It doesn't live in "secretly" in your app, slowing down resourses until the script has finished running. My script takes about 2min to run, this is the problem, even if I kill the webview or fragment the script lives on for 2 min anyhow.

Comment: Okej, will read through that page, but loading a blank URL have I already tried. I posted a question about this yesterday, today I think of different methods to solve it, like closing threads etc. Post from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714341/cannot-load-a-webview-inside-a-dialogfragment-if-previouse-load-didnt-complete-t

Comment: Problem is that once the javascript is set in action I cannot load a new Url even empty one before the script has finished.

Comment: @user3711421 Oh, I see. I think you should not use that time consuming javascript since it runs in a sandbox which we can't control. Why not get the page content first and process it with native java code and then post the  result to WebView, the processing is under control via this method.

Comment: @user3711421 I also have another solution: add a check state method in your JavaScriptInterface class and call that method during your processing loop and quit the loop if state is not match. Then the javascript will stop if you change the state to "quit state" when your fragment destroyed.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually a really good idea to do it with native code, I think that could work. Wonder why I haven't thought about that before. I the purpose is just to modify the HTML content (which I do now with javascript) than save that "new" page as a html file locally.

Comment: I like it, two solution which might actually solve the problem, will try the second one first since it req less modification. And since it might be an answer to this specific questions (and actually a few unanswered similar questions here on SO I have found while searching).

Comment: Second solution with a boolean method in the interface worked well, it might slow down the script a little since I now have to check this if statement before each iteration, but the slowdown was less than 10 sec which would give max 5% longer completion time. Now the script looks smt like for(24times) { if(window.HtmlViewer.isActive){RegExp}};... Edit your answer to how you though about with the second solution and I can mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Many thanks, I though I would be stuck with this today as well.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` and then set your thread to null.

**Edit**

According to javadocs, currentThread() grabs, well, the "currently executing thread object" which I assume grabs your thread if it's running. If you want to get more specific about what thread you're using, you can do

```
    //get a reference
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });

    //kill the thread
    t.interrupt();
    t = null;
```

**Edit** Oh, duh, I didn't notice the whole "javascript into webview" thing. My bad. Could you post a bit of your current implementation?

Comment: How do I set the thread to null? And is there a way of knowing which thread the javascript is using? the currentThread() is just a guess from my side.